# JQUERY - MouseOver DIV Event Issue

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV that shows when someone clicks Please Select:

[image]

HTML Below:

```
  <h3 id="joinCountryTitleH3" class="joinCreateAccountTitleH3">COUNTRY</h3>
  <span id="joinCountrySelectTextSPAN" class="joinCreateAccountDropDownTextSPAN">Please Select</span>
  <img src="http://www.content.dating/online-dating/dating-website/index-search-select.png" id="joinCountrySelectIMG" alt="Join Create Account Country DropDown"/>
  <div id="joinSearchCountryListContainerDIV" class="joinDropDownGenericDIV">
    <?php
      foreach($location->countryList as $key => $value) {
        $countryTemp = json_decode($key);
        if($countryTemp->zipEnabled) {
          echo '<span id="'.$countryTemp->countryCode.'" class="zipEnabled">'.$value.'</span><br>';
        }else{
          echo '<span id="'.$countryTemp->countryCode.'" class="zipDisabled">'.$value.'</span><br>';
        }
      }
    ?>
  </div>
  <span id="" class="joinSearchCountryDropdownSelectedSPAN"></span><br>
  <img src="http://www.content.dating/online-dating/dating-website/green-tick.png" id="joinCountryAcceptableIMG" class="joinGreenTickApprovalIMG" alt="Join Create Account Country Selection"/>
```

thx
Adam

Comment: could you post your HTML too please

Comment: I've added the HTML - the PHP just adds the Countries.

Comment: What is your question?